# What is the difference between a wait statement and using a while loop in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was wondering what is the difference between waiting for a flag to be set using a wait statement or a tradition loop until the flag is set.

```
wait (flag === 1); //Implementation 1

while ( flag != 1); //Implementation 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` statement blocks the current process until the expression becomes true.

The `while` loop you wrote becomes an infinite zero-delay loop if the expression is true (`flag` is false). This will hang simulation.